# Laravel : Query Builder Select on Where Like Statement

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a Query Builder problem on Laravel 5.4,

I want to select only certain field on where statement.

if I don't put WHERE statement function the SELECT function performed nicely, but when I put WHERE LIKE function then seems the SELECT function not working and it automatically selecting all (*)

Fyi, both user and address table has 'name' field. it only select name from user table. it work nicely.

```
DB::table('user')
-leftJoin('address', 'user.id', '=', 'address.user_id')
->select('user.name')
->paginate(1);
```

but this is not working

```
DB::table('user')
-leftJoin('address', 'user.id', '=', 'address.user_id')
->select('user.name')
->where('user.name', 'LIKE', '%jhon%')
->paginate(1);
```

how do I accomplish this? 
Any anwer will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Shouldn't `jhon` be `john`?

Answer (score 1):

Please write this. This will solve your problem

```
DB::table('user')
->leftJoin('address', 'user.id', 'address.user_id')
->where('user.name', 'LIKE', '%jhon%')
->select('user.name')
->get();
```

Comment: Still not working, the select statement seems not applied :9

Comment: Would you give me your table structure?  @Angger

Comment: @Angger Please see is there any name in 'jhon' in your database. I check my query. It works perfectly fine in my system.

Answer (score 0):

Its working. Give it a test.

```
DB::table('user')
->leftJoin('address', 'address.user_id', '=', 'user.id')
->where('user.name', 'like', '%jhon%')
->select('user.name')
->get();
```